# AWS Amplify Auth: How to disable AmplifyConfirmSignUp?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, components, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm currently using AWS Amplify auth, using Cognito for React authentication.
User sign-ups must confirm their new account by clicking on a confirmation link they receive via email.

When a submits their sign-up info, the next UI that is displayed is Confirm Signup that asks the user to confirm a code. I do not need this stage, as this is handled when the user confirms their email.

I'm using the react-ui Amplify components to control authentication and user signup/in/out.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.js";

import {
  AmplifyAuthenticator,
  AmplifySignUp,
  AmplifyConfirmSignUp,
  AmplifySignOut,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

import RouteContainer from "./components/RouteContainer";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AmplifyAuthenticator usernameAlias="email">
        <AmplifySignUp
          slot="sign-up"
          usernameAlias="email"
          formFields={[
            {
              type: "email",
              label: "Enter your email",
              placeholder: "Enter your email",
              required: true,
            },
            {
              type: "password",
              label: "Enter your password",
              placeholder: "",
              required: true,
            },
            {
              type: "custom:postcode",
              label: "Enter your postcode",
              placeholder: "",
              required: true,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <AmplifyConfirmSignUp/>

        </AmplifySignUp>
        <AmplifySignOut />
        <Router>
          <Container>
            <RouteContainer />
          </Container>
        </Router>
        <NavBar />
      </AmplifyAuthenticator>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there a prop I can pass to disable `<AmplifyConfirmSignUp/>` or another way to disable this from the standard sign-up flow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable verification in Cognito panel.

1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/
2. Click on "Manage User Pools"
3. In "General settings" click on "MFA and verifications"
4. Under "Which attributes do you want to verify?" choose "No verification"

Comment: How do you remove the component from the Amplify UI flow though? It's not in the amplify documentation.

Comment: Get message:  MFA cannot be turned off if an SMS role is configured? How solve this issue?

Comment: This one did not work for me. The response below worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can auto-confirm the user using a lambda function. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup)

- Create a lambda function ([See Docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/#set-up-a-function)) and return `autoConfirmUser` in the response.

```
exports.handler = async (event, _context, callback) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
  callback(null, event);
};
```

- Attach your lambda function with the **Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger**

[image]

There's one caveat though, if the user forgets his/her password. He wouldn't be able to recover it. So keep it in mind. [Here's more about this on Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3387#issuecomment-498460904)

I hope it helps :)

[Credits](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3387#issuecomment-498073586)

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer

Comment: The default Lambda code for me is in an `.mjs` file. It needs to be changed to `.js` to run this code snippet properly.