# How to auto-confirm a user in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify for auth purposes in my React Native application.
I get the error

```
error signing in {"code": "UserNotConfirmedException", "message": "User is not confirmed.", "name": "UserNotConfirmedException"}
```

if I try to sign in after sign up.
I couldn't find a working example in AWS docs.

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? Can you show the code/statements resulting in this error?

Comment: If you do not want to force user to confirm/verify the account, follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751412/aws-amplify-auth-how-to-disable-amplifyconfirmsignup

Comment: I also faced this issue and here's how I solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635650/8885198